# Why does a neo4j query return things out of order and how do I put things in order?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I expected a Neo4J query to return data listed in the same order for each entry (data 1 being first, data 2 second, or atleast a consistent order.)I executed a query to return a bunch of nodes of the same type and this came out:

Node1:
Data1, Data2

Node2:
Data1, Data2

Node3:
Data2, Data1

Node 4:
Data2, Data1

and so on and so forth.  Why are the properties in a random order and how can I fix this?

Edit:

I used this to create the nodes:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'filepath' AS row
CREATE (:Node {Data1: row.Data1, Data2: row.Data2})
```

I then used this query:

```
MATCH (n:Node) RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

It returns 18 rows which is right, but some of the nodes list the properties in a different order.

Comment: That's weird. Can you post your query. I could try something similar on a sample graph.

Comment: Added the queries that gave the output.  I have seen this happen before, but never figured out why it happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong, but lacking an `ORDER BY` clause in a query, no query language I've ever heard of (cypher included) guarantees any particular ordering.

Nodes in neo4j are maps (property name keys); in general, maps/hashtables don't guarantee ordering on keys unless you use particular types of maps.

I think for most data query languages, it's not a good idea to ever rely on implicit ordering; for example, if you just do `MATCH n RETURN n` what order will the `n` nodes come back in?  Creation order?  Last update order?   Numerically by ID?   I think the answer is "never assume, use `ORDER BY`".

If you need the order to be consistent, use `ORDER BY`.

You can do something like this:

```
MATCH n 
WITH id(n) as idn, keys(n) as kz unwind kz as items 
RETURN idn, items 
ORDER BY idn, items;
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood me.  I am not talking about ordering the nodes in a particular order, but how the properties are listed.  Basically, A node has property data1 and property data2.  However, data2 is sometimes put before data1 in the display of a nodes contents.

Comment: I understood -- it's the same issue really.  A node is a map of its properties.  Ordering on map keys isn't guaranteed.  Hence, the order of properties of a node isn't guaranteed.  If you want them to be ordered, use ORDER BY.

Comment: @cluemein Is there a reason you expect the properties to have a particular order? I assume you don't access them by order, but by key, no?

Comment: As far as I can tell, ORDER BY only works on sorting nodes based on the value of properties, not sorting properties based on the name of the property.

Comment: The `keys()` function pulls out the keys in a map.  The `unwind` function turns a collection into individual items, so combining them, `ORDER BY` should do it.   See update in the answer.